# How Do I not send file if data is not available via linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, email

I have the following code

```
for f in *@gmail.com*
do
    tmp=$( echo $f | awk -F'[_]' '{print $1}')
    tmp1=$( echo $f | awk -F'[_]' '{print $2 ,$3, $4,$5,$6}')
    newname1=${tmp1}
    newname=${tmp}
    echo $newname
    echo $newname1

    mv "$f" "${newname1}.csv"
    mail -a "${newname1}.csv" -s "working" $newname </dev/null
    mv "${newname1}.csv" $f
    rm -f "$f" "${newname1}.csv"
done
echo "mail -a "$newname1"  "working" $newname </dev/null "
```

This script works even if the CSV file contains no data. But no mail should be send, if that CSV file is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply send mail only, if the CSV file has more than one line:

```
if (( $(wc -l <YOUR_FILE.csv) > 1 ))
then
   mail ....
fi
```

Comment: Could you please explain <your_file.csv))
As you can see in the code its searching for files having @gmail.com so will it be a good option to put just after for f in *@gmail.com*???
If yes then please let me know what is wrong in this statement **if (( $(wc -l "$f") > 1 ))**

Comment: Try it on the command line. `wc -l FILE` outputs the number of lines **and** the filename. If you use input redirection, i.e. `wc -l <FILE`, you get only the number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Check if file size is Not zero then send mail

```
if [ -s ${newname1}.csv ] 
then
     mail -a "${newname1}.csv" -s "working" $newname </dev/null
fi
```

If File size is not empty and have some header then you can use this code to calculate no. of rows from file and check if no. of lines greater then one(header)

```
row=`cat ${newname1}.csv|wc -l` 
if [ $row -gt 1 ] 
then 
     mail -a "${newname1}.csv" -s "working" $newname </dev/null 
fi
```

Comment: It would have some size , while generating the file it gets a header which increases the size of the file from zero

Comment: Count no. of rows from csv file if more then one row in that file then you can send mail.
row=`cat ${newname1}.csv|wc -l`
if [ $row -gt 1 ]
then
         mail -a "${newname1}.csv" -s "working" $newname </dev/null
fi

Comment: Iam getting errors it says unary operator expected would you please show it in code format?

Comment: Is cat or wc command is not executed on your system it's installed by default on linux box.
you can check by directly run on terminal with test.csv file  > 
row=`cat test.csv | wc -l`
echo $row

Comment: This is counting the words not the lines inside the csv. For example it says cat: Abc@gmail.com: No such file or directory
cat:Data: No such file or directory..  etc

Comment: wc used to count words while "wc -l" used to count the line
it searching for wrong filename abc@gmail.com 

cat abc@gmail.com|wc -l

it should be csv file in newname1 variable

Comment: So if I put it just after for f in statement.. It would still count the words... right?

Comment: for f in *@gmail.com*
This is finding mail id not all csv files so  mv "$f" "${newname1}.csv"  this will look like this "abc@gmail.com.csv" which file not be there that's why it was giving error No such file or directory.

Comment: well the file generated is something like abc@gmail.com_data_stud_details.csv , all files has this same format
So its like mv helps in renaming the file.